# CSS perspective bug under firefox

Tags: css, perspective

I am having issues with the css "transform" property under firefox ( latest version + other versions tested )

Here is the transform applied :

```
  -moz-transform: perspective(2rem) rotateX(15deg) scaleY(1);
  -o-transform: perspective(2rem) rotateX(15deg) scaleY(1);
  -ms-transform: perspective(2rem) rotateX(15deg) scaleY(1);
  -webkit-transform: perspective(2rem) rotateX(15deg) scaleY(1);
  transform: perspective(2rem) rotateX(15deg) scaleY(1);
```

And the active element should have

```
  -moz-transform: perspective(0rem) rotateX(15deg) scaleY(1);
  -o-transform: perspective(0rem) rotateX(15deg) scaleY(1);
  -ms-transform: perspective(0rem) rotateX(15deg) scaleY(1);
  -webkit-transform: perspective(0rem) rotateX(15deg) scaleY(1);
  transform: perspective(0rem) rotateX(15deg) scaleY(1);
```

Here is a JSfiddle to test under chrome, and under firefox.
The "active" element does get a perspective change under chrome & others, while on firefox, it is not replaced.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w0fq6zfp/)

I searched for a similar case but it doesn't seem to have occured to someone else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like Firefox isn't playing nicely with setting a zero-value for the `transform: perspective(n)` rule.  What worked for me is just removing the perspective transform from the `.active` rule:

```
#owl-demo .owl-item.active > div{
  background: #6699ff;
  -moz-transform: rotateX(15deg) scaleY(1);
  -o-transform: rotateX(15deg) scaleY(1);
  -ms-transform: rotateX(15deg) scaleY(1);
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(15deg) scaleY(1);
  transform: rotateX(15deg) scaleY(1);
}
```

> Jump the the **Edit** section, the scenario below is incorrect, but still using it as a reference later

Additionally, I've found that the standalone `perspective` property does work fine with zero values.  If ensuring that value is set to zero is important to you, perhaps this will suffice:

```
#owl-demo .owl-item.active > div{
  background: #6699ff;
  -moz-transform: rotateX(15deg) scaleY(1);
  -moz-perspective: 0em;
  -o-transform: rotateX(15deg) scaleY(1);
  -ms-transform: rotateX(15deg) scaleY(1);
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(15deg) scaleY(1);
  transform: rotateX(15deg) scaleY(1);
  perspective: 0em;
}
```

### Edit

Turns out the second scenario is only "working" because it wasn't being used correctly.  For reference, `perspective` is a property intended to provide a 3D space to apply perspective to all 3D transformed child elements.  For example:

```
.owl-item {
  perspective: 2em;
}
#owl-demo .owl-item > div {
  margin: 0px 2px;
  height:100px;
  background: #6699ff;
  -moz-transform: rotateX(15deg) scaleY(1);
  -o-transform: rotateX(15deg) scaleY(1);
  -ms-transform: rotateX(15deg) scaleY(1);
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(15deg) scaleY(1);
  transform: rotateX(15deg) scaleY(1);
}
```

Because the child `divs` of the `owl-item` containers all have 3D transforms applied to them, this will apply a perspective to each of them.  However, this makes removing the perspective from a single child (the active div) impossible, at least with pure CSS.

`transform: perspective(n)`, on the other hand, affects each of the child elements individually, so the perspective can be removed by applying the active class:

```
#owl-demo .owl-item > div {
  margin: 0px 2px;
  height:100px;
  background: #cccccc;
  -moz-transform: perspective(2em) rotateX(15deg) scaleY(1);
  -o-transform: perspective(2em) rotateX(15deg) scaleY(1);
  -ms-transform: perspective(2em) rotateX(15deg) scaleY(1);
  -webkit-transform: perspective(2em) rotateX(15deg) scaleY(1);
  transform: perspective(2em) rotateX(15deg) scaleY(1);
  transition: transform .5s;
}
#owl-demo .owl-item.active > div{
  background: #6699ff;
  -moz-transform: rotateX(15deg) scaleY(1);
  -o-transform: rotateX(15deg) scaleY(1);
  -ms-transform: rotateX(15deg) scaleY(1);
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(15deg) scaleY(1);
  transform: rotateX(15deg) scaleY(1);
}
```

Hopefully this helps with the understanding of the 2 perspective approaches.  I know it helped me :)

Comment: Damn, didn't think about that one, since I needed it animated, I thought it wouldn't get animated. Thanks a lot !

Comment: I can't get the "perspective" css attribute to work, i don't get any result like this : https://jsfiddle.net/w0fq6zfp/7/

Comment: It looks like I jumped the gun on what `perspective` is actually doing.  Turns out that it's intended to be set on a parent element and the perspective is applied to all 3D transformed child elements.  In your case, wanting to remove perspective from a single child element, you'll want to go the route of removing the `perspective(n)` from the active element.  I'll update the answer with some more information

Answer (score 0):

Apologies for not contributing to the actual problem, but: considering you are using `perspective` for shaping the navigation-tabs, it seems like this wouldn't work in the real-world. (Yes I know, skewomorphism is out, but still – imagine you'd have to build the layout in paper, like Google's material-thing, you couldn't bend the tabs like they are…